# Bigquery UDF that returns latest partition

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, bigquery-udf

I'm trying to build a BigQuery UDF that returns the latest partition DATE for a partitioned table, given the dataset name and table name as parameters to the UDF. I cannot use BQ scripting to get latest partition since I need to save my final query as a view definition (and views don't support scripting).
The UDF right now returns an error message 'Not found: Dataset my-project-id:dataset_name was not found in location northamerica-northeast1'.
The error message makes sense, but I don't want to hard-code my actual dataset's name in the UDF. How do I get around this problem ?

```
    CREATE FUNCTION `my-project-id.test_dataset`.get_latest_partition(dataset_name STRING, tab_name STRING)
  RETURNS DATE
     AS (
       (SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', MAX(partition_id)) FROM dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE table_name = tab_name)
       )
```

Comment: I believe the project and dataset reference is required for this udf based on this documentation: [Link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#default_project_in_sql_expressions)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to pass dynamically the name of the dataset inside the function as you do with tab_name because it's completing the ".INFORMATION_SCHEMA". You can't concatenate or scripting (format, declare) in that case.